# Zend_Form not displaying data

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

Here is my code:

```
<?php

class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->_forward('search');
    }

    public function searchAction()
    {
        if($this->getRequest()->isGet())
        {
            $form = $this->getForm();

            $value  = $form->getValue('search');
            echo "'", $value, "'"; // <-- prints ''
        }

        $this->view->form = $this->getForm();
    }

    public function getForm()
    {
        $form = new Zend_Form();
        $form->setAction('/index/search')
             ->setMethod('get');

        $search = $form->createElement('text', 'search');
        $search->addFilter('StripTags')
               ->addFilter('StringTrim');

        // Add elements to form:

        $form->addElement($search)
             ->addElement('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Search'));

        return $form;
    }
}
```

In *searchAction()* $value is always blank even after I submit the form and I see the data in the URL. What is the problem?

EDIT: I fixed getValue() to getValues() but it still isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you are able to use ->getValue(); you have to validate the form.

```
 public function searchAction()
    {
        if($this->getRequest()->isGet())
        {
            $form = $this->getForm();

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $value  = $form->getValue('search');
                echo "'", $value, "'"; // <-- prints ''
            } else {
                // what ever
            }



        }

        $this->view->form = $this->getForm();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `$this->_request->getParams()` to `$form->isValid()`, otherwise the form will not have any values to work with.

Answer (score 0):

The function you want is *getValue*, not getValues.

A subtle difference but they do two totally different things.

Comment: OK, I fixed that but still no love. I can't get $value to be anything but empty.